# Making ObservableCollection of images appear nicely on screen

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have a method which populates an ObservableCollection. This ObservableCollection is bound to my XAML, and it appears on screen. Currently, however, it merely extends downwards, one image after another like so : 
[image: As you can see, after 3 images, it displays no more and cuts off the image halfway through.]

What I would like would be for the images to be displayed in a grid fashion, with, for example, 5 per line, allowing the user to scroll downwards. How could I accomplish this ? An example of what I would like :

[image: From Google images. With a static number of images this is easy to accomplish, with a binding to an ObservableCollectiout, however, I am lost.]

As I understand, it may not be considered "Metro"/"Windows 8 app style" to extend downwards, if so, how would I emulate the functionality shown in the image, so that the overflow extends to the right, allowing you to continue scrolling to the right?

My code at the moment :

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listOfImages}"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image x:Name="images" Source="{Binding}" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="200"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

UPDATE :

I have now added a WrapGrid, but it is still rendering incorrectly, like so :

[image: I have now added a WrapGrid, but it is still rendering incorrectly, like so]

Here is the code I am using :

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listOfImages}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListView Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapGrid Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image x:Name="images" Source="{Binding}" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="200"/>
                                </WrapGrid>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </ItemsControl>
```

What have I misunderstood here ? Thanks a lot.

UPDATE :

Simple code :

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listOfImages}">
                                <WrapGrid Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image x:Name="images" Source="{Binding}" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="200"/>
                                </WrapGrid>
                  </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `WrapPanel` with the [`Orientation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.orientation.aspx) set to `Orientation.Vertical`.

Like this it will first fill the first column, overflow to the second column and so on, extending to the right.

See also the documentation:

> If the Orientation property is set to Horizontal, child content forms horizontal rows first and if necessary forms vertical stacks of rows. If the Orientation property is set to Vertical, child content is first positioned in a vertical column, and if there is not enough space, wrapping occurs and additional columns in the horizontal dimension are added.

---

The `WrapGrid` you are using is a bit strange. It looks like you have to use it like so:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listOfImages}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" Height="200"
                   Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have tried to implement this, but ran into a problem. I have updated my question to reflect this. Thanks again :)

Comment: That looks pretty wrong. Why are you nesting a ListView inside an ItemsControl when you should just be using a WrapPanel?

Comment: I have updated to show what code I am using now, but it is returning the error message : "WrapGrid can only be used to display items within an ItemsControl."...which makes no sense to me :)